# Why am I getting two method calls in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I have the following example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.testMethod = function() {
    alert('hi');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{testMethod()}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have called the method only once in view template. But why is it executed twice?

Comment: That is how angular digest cycle works. Whatever binded to the view will get call on each digest cycle.

Comment: @PankajParkar If method is called twice, why is it not happening to expressions?

Comment: @PankajParkar, What could be those 2 cycles ?

Comment: @RayonDabre because they are expression in `string` formats.internally it gets evaluates against `$scope`..

Comment: Did you try ` {{ ::(testMethod()) }}`?;

Comment: @Hitmands One time binding didn't work in this case. Even that produces two method call

Answer (score 12):

When you use functions in binding expressions Angular will reevaluate the expression on every $digest phase. The reason behind this is that functions can return a response but there is no way for Angular to know if the result won't change in the next function call.

Angular ensures that it will show the latest correct up to date value in the only way possible in this case - by calling the function every time there is a change in the scope.

You'll see people calling this "$digest phase". It can occur due to many reasons. For the sake of this explanation I'm simplifying stuff. If you want to know more read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

As a general rule - avoid binding to a function. Instead remember the function response in a `$scope` variable and bind to it instead. Binding many times to a function might lead to performance issues when bindings count grows in your project.

### EDIT - Answer to sahbeewah comments (see below)

Let's change the post example. Open the console and run the code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var i = 0;

  $scope.testMethod = function() {
    alert('hi');

    i++;
    return i; // Return a different value every time
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{testMethod()}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*For the example purposes it's important for `$scope.testMethod` to return different value every time it's called.*

You'll notice the following:

- "Hi" alert will be shown multiple times
- After you see it multiple times the following error will appear:

  > Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

So, what happened? Every time we change the `$scope` state here angular runs another digest phase until it "stabilizes" (*there are no more changes*). There is a limit on 10 consecutive $digest phases.

In the thread post angular calls $digest when the controller is attached and then, because we change the $scope, it calls one more digest. If we remove all the bindings from the code only one digest will occur.

We can easily check this. Remove the `{{testMethod()}}` line from the example and then place a breakpoints in angular code: **$digest, line 16700 (*angular 1.5.0*)**.
On this line you'll see `if ((dirty || asyncQueue.length) && !(ttl--)) {`.

Your breakpoint will now be hit only once. Let's look 2 lines above. Angular team wrote an interesting comment there:

```
// `break traverseScopesLoop;` takes us to here
```

It's a self explanatory comment and if we go up to line 16629 we'll see

```
do { // "while dirty" loop
```

There is a variable in the code named "dirty" that creates a `do...while` loop. While the scope is **dirty** (*there are changes detected*) you'll stay in this loop. A change is any change on any scope variable used in any way by any kind of binding (*$watch*).

That's why we have 2 $digest phases here.

You can find Angular 1.5 [here](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js). For debugging purposes I've switched to the non-minified versions.

Comment: *"As a general rule - avoid binding to a function."* This is not a good advice at all. Getters are prefectly valid way of creating expressions. Perhaps you have variable `fullName` but you'd only want to display the first name, so you'd do `$scope.getFirstName = () => fullName.split(' ')[0]` or something. Just make sure the functions always return the same value if conditions haven't changed and don't make assumptions about how many times angular will call the function (no side effects).

Comment: I'm not saying that getters are not valid ways for creating expressions. They are. 

Even if your function returns the same value every single time Angular will still call it on every $digest phase. If you use them only for simple getters and don't abuse them it's fine.

@noppa Your getter function does array split and then retrieves the value. String split is a heavy operation and it also creates a new array instance. That's exactly the kind of thing you don't want to do in a function you are using for binding. You'll be creating a new array on every $digest phase.

Comment: @avladov, There are cases where `expression` must go through `digest cycle` so it depends on the _use-case_

Comment: @avladov The example there had to be quite hacky so it would fit nicely to an SO comment. If the getters cause actual performance problems, they should obviously be fixed, possibly by storing the result somewere. But setting the results to $scope properties will often lead to lots of setters scattered around the code. Like in that example you'd have to remeber to update firstName every time the fullName changes and had it more variables affecting the results, the code could quickly become a mess.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the second digest phase is being executed.

Comment: It shouldn't clutter your code. You can always create value objects using factory that will store the computed values. Also writing a getter function is not less "cluttering". It's better to use filters for this (_filters have the same limitation as functions - they should be simple, no complex convoluted code logic_). Also writing getters in the controller as functions will lead to "fat" controllers. When I'm writing code I want my controllers to be as thin as possible.

Comment: @avladov You can create getter logic in factories just as easy as you can create value objects. By scattered code I meant that when variables x, y and z affect the value of $scope.someValue, you'll need to **manually** update $scope.someValue every time x, y or z changes, which might be often if you have dynamic content in your app. Not the case with getters. I see your point about performance, but I wouldn't make design sacrifices for it before performance causes actual problems.

Comment: This is the correct answer nontheless, I just disagree about the last point. Still upvoted.

Comment: Again, this doesn't explain why the second digest phase is being executed. It is not obvious why angular would need to call the binding expression twice. Saying "because of digest cycles", "read about digest cycles" is a poor answer.

Comment: @sahbeewah There is either two $digest cycles happening or angular is ensuring the return value has settled by calling the method twice in the same $digest cycle. I'd consider either one of those expected behaviour.

Comment: @noppa This answer doesn't explain that. Hint: there is only one digest cycle, so this answer isn't just lacking in any useful information, it is also misleading. It also doesn't make sense that angular is "ensuring the return value has settled". So what is triggering angular to require more than one check? As there is nothing obvious that shows why angular would need to re-check its watch list in this scenario.

Comment: @sahbeewah I've edited my post with some additional explanations and comments on the angular code.

Answer (score 1):

avladov's answer is correct, but perhaps doesn't cover what sahbeewah asked.
The update on the answer is explanatory, but honestly the answer boils down to much simpler point.

- Angular pairs all watchers with special property (called `last` in v1.4.10).
- The initial value of `last` is *function initWatchVal()* which is a private value in angular and thus you cannot return without some serious hacks.
- Dirty checking works by evaluating the expression and comparing to previous evaluation (the value of `last`).
- If these values don't match, new round of evaluations is scheduled.

The point being: as you can't return the initial value, new round of evaluations is **always** scheduled after the first evaluation of new watchers.